# Chrome extension how to detect that domain has changed in specific tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am trying to detect when a specific tab has a domain change - for example, I leave facebook.com to go to stackoverflow.com. But I only want to detect it for the given tab - so not for if I go to facebook.com in one tab and then stackoverflow.com in another. When this event happens, I need to know which domain unloaded. So if in a specific tab I navigate from facebook.com to stackoverflow.com I will need the event to trigger and "facebook.com" to be stored in a variable.

I thought the following would work, but the tab id changes (and I think is sometimes loading the new tab id vs the one for the unloaded page??) so it's not working. Any ideas?

In content script:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 

        var host = location.host;

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({unloadEvent : host}, function(response){

            if(response.isSuccess){
                console.log('unload message sent');
            }
        });
    }
```

In background:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log('request is ', request);
    ...

    else if (request.unloadEvent){

        var queryInfo = {
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
            };

       chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
           var tab = tabs[0];
           var url = tab.url, id = tab.id, host =request.unloadEvent;

           console.log('the current url is ' + url + ' and the host is ' + host);

           if(!TABS[id]){
            console.log("maybe im a new page?");

           }
           /*if(tabs[id] && tabs[i] !== request.unloadEvent){
            console.log("im a different site in that tab");
           }*/

           TABS[id] = host;

           console.log(TABS);

           sendResponse({isSuccess : true});
       });
    }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. The tabid changes only when you remove/close the tab and using the content script is a bad idea.

The right fit for you is to use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) like in the following:

```
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            alert('tabid: ' + tabid + 'URL: ' + changeInfo.url + 'Tab status: ' + changeInfo.status);
        }
    });
```

This must be included in the background script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no way to tell if the page itself has changed within a specific tab? And the tab Id is changing every now and then when I change the domain within the tab but only sometimes - weird.